# Unexpected file found in package directory: force-app/main/default/lwc/jsconfig.json

Tags: json, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

I have create a sfdx project and working on to migrate a VF page into lightning web component. At the first I have created the LWC components and pushed it to the scratch org, but now I am having issue while pushing the jsconfig.json file into the org.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the root of your project, add a `**/jsconfig.json` entry to the `.forceignore`. This file must be added to the `.forceignore` file since it for local development only and should not be pushed to your org.

The `jsconfig.json` file is necessary for the Lightning Web Components language server protocol (LSP), which helps with things like autocomplete of custom types in your IDE.

Note that this file is automatically added by the VS Code Lightning Web Components extension (salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lwc), which *also* adds the `**/jsconfig.json` entry to the `.forceignore` file for you. Before installing the LWC extension, make sure to install VS Code [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode).

**Edit (2/14/2019):**

It actually looks like the Lightning Web Components extension is included in the Salesforce Extension Pack now so you shouldn't need to install both separately. See the [dev guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/install_setup_develop) for more doc on getting your local environment set up.

Answer (score 5):

Also add **/.eslintrc.json to .forceignore. it gets generated when using VS code